# CollectionView celda con Highlight

Tags: ios, objective-c

Tengo un collectionView con varias celdas, cuando pulso una necesito que se vea como que ha sido pulsada con un color o animación.

Para ello uso:

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didHighlightItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  MiCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"misCeldas" forIndexPath:indexPath];
  cell.vHighlight.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255/255.0 green:255/255.0 blue:153/255.0 alpha:1];
  }
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView  didUnhighlightItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  MiCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"misCeldas" forIndexPath:indexPath];
  cell.vHighlight.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
  }

Cuando pulso la celda he comprobado que va al método correspondiente pero cuando cambio el color de background de la celda no se refleja en la vista.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo probaría a usar `func cellForItem(at: IndexPath)` para asegurarme de que se está recuperando la celda que se realmente se está mostrando para ese indexPath.

Podría pasar que `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:` devolviera una celda que en ese momento no se está visualizando y, por ello, se considera que se puede reutilizar en ese momento para ese indexPath.

Espero haber sido de ayuda.

Comment: Tal como tengo escrito el código necesito usar dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:

Comment: Lo he probado y mas o menos me funciona, aunque he tenido que hacer un cast a una clase que deriva de collectionView. ¿ Se podría hacer con dequeueReusabkeCellWithReuseIdentifier ?. Gracias !!

Comment: Genial! Me alegro de que ahora te funcione :)

La verdad es que no se me ocurre cómo hacerlo con dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier sin que nos encontremos con el problema de antes, recuperar una celda que no se esté mostrando, me parece que no se puede controlar eso.

No acabo de entender por qué no te sirve cellForItemAtIndexPath. ¿Usas una clase que extiende de UICollectionView y por esto hay algún problema?

Comment: No, alfinal si que me ha ido bien pero en lo que resta de código las celdas las tengo llamadas con el dequeueReusableCell. También he probado otra opción que era con un Tap Gesture Recognizer en la Celda y al pulsar controlar por código el resaltado de la celda, en este caso era mas estable pues con el didHighlightItemAtIndexPath la pulsación tenia que mantenerla mas tiempo para resaltar la celda.